# Configure UART/COM in Linux using Hyper-V Generation 2 VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, hyper-v, com, named-pipe

I've setup Linux Mint x64 in Hyper-V as a Generation 2 Virtual Machine on my Windows 10 desktop. I would like to attach a USB->Serial converter (FT232RL) to the VM, so I can program and debug embedded hardware. In Windows the FT232RL shows up as a "USB Serial Port (COMx)" and is working fine. When I'm using VirtualBox I can just attach or detach the COM Port from the VM, and everything works just fine.

Generation 2 VM's in Hyper-V don't have the COM ports/named pipes show in their settings, unlike generation 1 VM's, so I'm not sure how to access the appropriate settings. There is an article [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jhoward/2013/10/31/hyper-v-generation-2-virtual-machines-part-5/) ([more details](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848616(v=wps.630).aspx)) that shows what I want to achieve, except I'm using Linux instead of Windows as my guest OS.

So, how would I go about setting this up? I've already had a look at setserial in Linux, but so far haven’t arrived at a solution.

Comment: I did just a quick read; sounds like you want to detach the USB device from the host and have it handled by the guest, no?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Can Hyper-V do USB Pass-through? I was under the impression that only VMware ESX/ESXi 5.1 or newer could handle this properly.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but even if the VM can pipe the serial data that will be fine for me. As long as Linux treats the pipe like a regular serial port/USB device

Comment: Any answer? I have the same problem to solve.

Comment: I didn't end up solving it. I'm still using virtual box as my primary VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that there are at least three ways to get this working, which I've found out over time.

The first is quite straightforward using Remote Desktop to access the virtual machine instead of the hyper-v launcher. Of course, this requires the guest OS to have a remote desktop server and the firewall to open and have the IP address in range for the host. Using RDP, you can go Show Options -> Local Resources/Local devices and resources -> More -> Select 'Ports'. Then connect as normal.

This solution is only good for Generation 1 VMs as it does not create a named pipe itself on the host OS. Gen 1 VMs allow the user to create a named pipe through the VMs settings menu. The second solution is use [COMpipe](https://github.com/tdhoward/COMpipe). This involves using the hyper-v settings to set up a named pipe on one of the COM ports e.g. MySerialPort on COM1 (Creates named pipe path: \.\pipe\MySerialPort). Then on the host OS run an admin PS and issue a command like: `COMpipe.exe -b 115200 -c \\.\COM5 -p \\.\pipe\MySerialPort` where COM5 is the COM port on the host OS you are trying to use. If everything works, you should be able to use COM1 in the guest OS and have it map straight through to COM5 on the host. From experience, an error of GLE=5 means the named pipe is not created in the guest OS.

The third solution is much more complex and is described [here](http://www.goodjobsucking.com/?p=214) ([backup link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yPk0aiTPDuQJ:www.goodjobsucking.com/%3Fp%3D214%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nz)). This involves building hub4com and running com0com (also as admin) and a few other scripts with the hub4com project on both the guest and host OS.

As an aside, you can map a COM port to a named pipe (needs to be created by some app) using [Set-VMComPort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmcomport?view=windowsserver2019-ps) and view the mappings with [Get-VMComPort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vmcomport?view=windowsserver2019-ps). This is needed for Gen 2 Hyper-V VMs as COM ports are [not visible](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn282285(v=ws.11)) (see note on Generation 2 FAQ) in the settings when configuring Gen 2 VMs.